# How to use chrome dev tools to find elements based on css class or id?

Tags: html, google-chrome, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

Long time automation developer here (just for context).
It's been bugging me for quite a while that the dev tools in chrome used to find elements just don't seem to work as I expect.  Hopefully someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

Looking at , say, sauce labs page: https://saucelabs.com/blog/selenium-tips-finding-elements-by-their-inner-text-using-contains-a-css-pseudo-class

ok now that page has div's and anchors

[image]

and indeed I can do `find ('a')` or `find('div')`

but why do I have a problem using classes or id's ?

[image]

Comment: In Chrome dev tools console, find() is an alias of "find on page". It searches visible text only. If you need to find elements in the DOM, use `document.querySelectorAll();`

Comment: Great!  and without all it find the first - which if unique is obv 1 element - and returns that single element

Answer (score 17):

The `find()` method refers to [`window.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find), a non-standard API for the browser's built-in Find function. It does not find web elements the same way Selenium or Capybara do, and so it does not parse the input as a selector.

You find elements with selectors in Chrome DevTools using `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()`. There are no special methods in Chrome DevTools for this, however it does provide the `$()` and `$$()` aliases (respectively) to save you time and keystrokes.

Comment: @TemaniAfif you can usually ping him in the [HTML/CSS](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign) room as well if there is a particular question that he may provide help with... not to make a habit out of it or anything, but it does help keep comments clean!

Comment: @TylerH yes sure, still not used to chat rooms, But I will ;) ... and don't worry about comments, BoltClock will clean them :p . As as side note, your title edit of that question was not relevant, you changed the meaning a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jquery code in chrome console, for example if you want to find something with **class** of "foo" you can write `$('.foo')` or a **id** of "bar" you write `$('#bar')`

You can read all about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/)

Also you can just google what you want "Jquery how to find a div with id"

Comment: Chrome doesn't bundle or build jQuery into its console. The $() function that Chrome uses is just a built-in alias of document.querySelector(). If you wanted to use jQuery you would have to assume jQuery is loaded in the first place (which would have been reasonable 5 years ago, but not today, considering sites like GitHub are actively moving *away* from it). And if it isn't, you'd have to load it, which is entirely too much work for something that is already available natively...